# Deep Link URL fail to redirect to teams tab in mobile app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

> I am trying to redirect to the teams tab via my teams bot.
>
> > The code is working fine in browsers but not working on teams mobile app.

Comment: Are you following the correct format for Deep Linking?

Comment: Yes, I am following the correct doc and it is working well in browsers but in mobile app, I am getting a popup displaying error message - **Sorry we cannot take you to this destination at this time.**

Comment: Please provide some updates.

Comment: I don't have any other ideas - hopefully one of the Teams support people from Microsoft on this site do...

Comment: We tried repro'ing this issue at our end and it works fine on browsers and mobiles. Please try using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab)

Comment: I'm using nodeJS and still getting same error and this is how my url looks - `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/${this.appId}/${this.tabEnitityId}?webUrl=${this.fallbackURL}&context=${contextJson}`

Comment: can you please post URL to bot as a message and check it in mobile and confirm here?

Comment: @AyushArya were you ever able to solve this? I have a similar problem, but only in the Teams Android App. Deep link in OpenUrl action in an adaptive card works in MS Teams desktop, browser and iOS app, but doesn't load our the tab in Android. e.g. link `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/4616d826-1fb2-4d0e-ab1a-3353ee8fe96d/main?context=%7B%22channelId%22%3A%2219%3A8d333c4d488d48f9875681c3b32692ba%40thread.skype%22%2C%22subEntityId%22%3A%22urn%3Aoid%3A2.49.0.1.124.0349187357.2021%22%7D`